# Access files with OWC Envoy Pro Enclosure

Tags: macbook-pro, partition, ssd, external-disk

My MacBook Pro 2015 13" stopped booting. My last backup is too old so I bought and OWC Envoy Pro Enclosure to retrieved data.

The only other Apple machine that I can use is an iMac 27" 2012. I put my disk in the enclosure and plugged it to the iMac. However, I can't see the files. In "disk utility", I have 3 new partitions: "disk3s5", "Macintosh HD - Data" and "Update". The first one is always greyed. In the Finder I can only see the files from the partition named "Update". If I try to access the main partition, it doesn't stop loading. The iMac has macOS 10.15.7 and the internal HDD uses APFS file system.

`diskutil list external` gives me this:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         250.8 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     207.4 GB   disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 284.0 MB   disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                622.1 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      12.9 GB    disk3s4
   5:                APFS Volume                         15.3 GB    disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume Update                  376.8 KB   disk3s6
```

I tried to edit `/etc/fstab` with `UUID=my_uuid none apfs rw,noauto 0 0` but nothing changed. I also tried `defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages skip-verify YES`.

What should I do to see the files?